Explanation of complex number in alternating current
Can anyone pls explain how complex numbers are used in alternating current,I was reading about rl circuit and found out they changed voltage $$V \sin \omega t \tag{1}$$ to $V e^{i\omega t}$.
as we know Euler equation was
$$
e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta +i \sin \theta \tag{2}
$$
So how can we convert $\sin \omega t$ to $e^{i \omega t}$?  As we don't have $i$ in equation (1) and also how complex numbers work for waves? what do the imaginary and real parts symbolize for the wave?

This question is clear. It might have been phrased "Why is the complex function $V = V_0e^{i\omega t}$ used to represent voltage when it is really given by the real function $V = V_0\sin(\omega t)$?

More on complex numbers in electric circuits.

"So how can we convert $sin(ωt )$to $ e^{iωt}$?", $Re(z)=\frac{1}{2}(z+\bar{z});,;Im(z)=\frac{1}{2i}(z-\bar{z});,;|z|=\sqrt{z\bar{z}};;$i.e.$;;z=Re(z)+Im(z)i$

Hint: the circuits you are talking about are governed by linear differential equations; try to apply a Fourier Transform to the entire equation.

it is a calculation tool, what is important is what is 'measurable' physically, it is as if I said: I have $X=a(dollar)+by(books)+cz(laptop)+...$,everything must be converted into dollar (simple to understand) which is the norm .

Hi, welcome to Physics SE. The voltage solves a linear differential equation whose complex solution set is closed under conjugation, so even though we want a real solution it's most convenient to study the complex solutions first.

@TheTiler Why don't you write that with a bit more beef on the bones as an answer?

FlatterMann Because I don't know exactly where it's stuck, and that's the way I do it at work: I come up with all the ideas that seem to have a link with the problem, and sometimes my colleagues say oh yes, that's the solution, but I don't even remember when I said it :-) (In my job (repetitive), most of the time I am a machine (physically and mentally), if not I waste time.)

because the true nature of certain functions, so-called transfer functions, such as impedance, that characterize linear lumped element circuits can only be understood in the complex plane. The simplest example of such characterization is a polynomial with real coefficients but because some of its roots are complex valued to understood its true nature you need to move away from the real axis.

This question is similar to: What is the physical significance of the imaginary part when plane waves are represented as $e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is really just a mathematically convenience.
A lot of circuit analysis tasks are a lot easier to do with complex sine waves and complex impedances. Instead of slogging through the analysis with real sine waves and time-domain differential equations you simply add an imaginary part, do the math in complex numbers. When you  are done you get the real solution simply by throwing away the imaginary part of the complex solutions.

So how can we convert $\sin \omega t$ to $e^{i \omega t}$?

By simple convention. Any real signal $x(t) = cos(\omega t + \varphi)$ can be represented as $x(t) = \Re[{e^{i\omega t + \varphi}}]$.

what do the imaginary and real parts symbolize for the wave?

The imaginary part has no physical meaning. It's simply a mathematical convenience. You discard it once you are done with the math.
